# How to apply authentication to rest endpoint URL?

Tags: 8

I can access the rest endpoint URL for a node in JSON format (e.g. https://192.168.1.235/rest_endpoint/node/1142?_format=json) even if we are not logged-in to the sever.

Is there any way to apply authentication to access this URL?

Comment: You could disable the `View published content` permission for anonymous users, and that should do it.

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein its not a **view** or **content** though ! . its rest enpoint output of a node in json format

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein , It worked by the way ! thanks .but if we need to give permission to view some pages to anonymous users , what should do ?

Answer (score 1):

Since rest callbacks run through Drupal's normal roles/permissions layer, you can just disable the `View published content` permission for anonymous users, then they won't be able to fetch the JSON for the View.

If you need finer grained control, you'll have to use [hook_node_grants()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_grants/8.2.x).